# Planner Combination Problem on Graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, combinations

I ran into a Graph Problem.

Suppose G is A Planner Graph with 100 Vertices such that if connect each two Non-adjacent vertices, the resulting graph would be non-planner. what is the number of edges of G?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are talking about a simple graph (no loops, no multiple edges).  Then every region in the graph has degree at least $3$.  However if there is a region of degree more than $3$ then your condition is not satisfied.  So every region has degree $3$ exactly.  Also, the graph is connected as otherwise your condition is not satisfied.  Therefore we have
$$r+v=e+2\ ,\quad 3r=2e\ ,\quad v=100$$
from which you can find $r=196$ and $e=294$.